# Need a way to write my Huffman tree to my encoding

Tags: c++, compression, huffman-code, lossless-compression

I'm working on an efficient implementation of Huffman compression, but it needs to be done in a unique way: I need to find a way to write my Huffman tree to my encoding before passing it on to the decoder, as for this specific project we are only allowed to pass one pointer to the decoder. I cannot pass the tree itself, because then I would be unable to pass the encoding.

Does anyone has a good way of efficiently storing my Huffman tree in my Huffman encoding?

I'm currently implementing this using C++.

Comment: You can't store the Huffman tree _inside_ your Huffman encoding - the decoder must know it before decoding. Without knowing how your decoder is set up this answer is impossible to answer.

Comment: @orlp I haven't started writing the decoder yet since I am trying to figure this out first. I guess what I am trying to say is that I need to dedicate some portion of my huffman encoding to somehow representing the tree. My professor is not allowing us to pass the Huffman tree to the decoder.

Comment: Typically, the huffman tree is passed as a header pacakge for the data.  This does decrease overall efficiency, but can be mitigated by having a lot of encoded data.  or the huffman frequency data can be encoded with a more efficient compressor, but that is also probably beyond scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store the Huffman tree *inside* your Huffman encoding - the decoder must know it before decoding.

You must [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your Huffman tree and prepend it to your Huffman encoded data. Your decoder must deserialize the tree before decoding.

Comment: Or use a dynamic huffman encoding system, but that is probably way beyond scope here...

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to or need to transmit the tree.  All you need to send is the number of bits for each symbol.  From that you can construct the same [canonical code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) on both ends.